# Javascript (Electron) 'TypeError: Cannot set property 'checked' of undefined'

Tags: javascript, electron

I am creating a tray application with Electron but I can't figure out why this wouldn't work. I am very new to JavaScript. I looked through answers on here but most of them don't work/are confusing to me.

Basically, what I want the application to do is load settings from `electron-store` into the application on launch. However, once it reaches the `if` statement, it throws an error.

This is the only code I have so far:

```js
const path = require('path')
const { app, Menu, Tray } = require('electron');
const Store = require('electron-store');

const store = new Store();

let tray = null;

function setDefaultStore() {
    if (!store.has('theme')) {
        store.set('theme', 'dark');
    }

    if (!store.has('style')) {
        store.set('style', 'colourful');
    }
}

function run() {
    setDefaultStore()

    tray = new Tray(path.join(__dirname, 'images/trayIcon.png'))

    const contextMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
        {
            label: 'Theme', submenu: [
                {
                    label: 'Platinum (light)',
                    type: 'radio',
                    checked: false,
                    click() {
                        store.set('theme', 'light');
                    }
                },
                {
                    label: 'Graphite (dark)',
                    type: 'radio',
                    checked: true,
                    click() {
                        store.set('theme', 'dark');
                    }
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            label: 'Style', submenu: [
                {
                    label: 'Colourful',
                    type: 'radio',
                    checked: true,
                    click() {
                        store.set('style', 'colourful');
                    }
                },
                {
                    label: 'Mono',
                    type: 'radio',
                    checked: false,
                    click() {
                        store.set('style', 'mono');
                    }
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            type: 'separator'
        },
        {
            label: 'Update'
        },
        {
            type: 'separator'
        },
        {
            label: 'Quit',
            click() {
                app.quit();
            }
        }
    ])

    if (store.get('theme') == 'light') { // Throws error here!
        contextMenu.items[1].submenu[1].checked = true;
        contextMenu.items[1].submenu[2].checked = false;
    } else if (store.get('theme') == 'dark') {
        contextMenu.items[1].submenu[1].checked = false;
        contextMenu.items[1].submenu[2].checked = true;
    }
    
    if (store.get('style') == 'colourful') {
        contextMenu.items[2].submenu[1].checked = true;
        contextMenu.items[2].submenu[2].checked = false;
    } else if (store.get('style') == 'mono') {
        contextMenu.items[2].submenu[1].checked = false;
        contextMenu.items[2].submenu[2].checked = true;
    }

    tray.setToolTip('Vanilla Auto');
    tray.setContextMenu(contextMenu);
}

app.on('ready', run);
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'checked' of undefined
```

Comment: you don't have index 2, so submenu[2] is undefined, instead, use submenu[0] and submenu[1]

Comment: I just tried it now but still didn't run correctly @MUHAMMADILYAS

Comment: change item index as well and that should work

Comment: Tried it but gives the same error

Comment: so simply track the value for context.items[0] and check is submenu is there?

Comment: If you mean to use console.log with the submenu, yes it sees it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it and it was *really simple*. (aka 5 hours)

Apparently, any `submenu` in Electron (possibly JS, I'm not sure) has an array called `items`. All I had to do was add `.items` after `submenu` and it worked!

This is what the updated `if` statement is:

```js
    if (store.get('theme') == 'light') {
        contextMenu.items[0].submenu.items[0].checked = true;
        tray.setContextMenu(contextMenu);
        console.log('Theme "Light" set');
    }
    if (store.get('theme') == 'dark') {
        contextMenu.items[0].submenu.items[1].checked = true;
        tray.setContextMenu(contextMenu);
        console.log('Theme "Dark" set');
    }
    
    if (store.get('style') == 'colourful') {
        contextMenu.items[1].submenu.items[0].checked = true;
        tray.setContextMenu(contextMenu);
        console.log('Style "Colourful" set');
    }
    if (store.get('style') == 'mono') {
        contextMenu.items[1].submenu.items[1].checked = true;
        tray.setContextMenu(contextMenu);
        console.log('Style "Mono" set');
    }
```